# Twitter user_timeline.json showing only latest tweet even though count = 5

Tags: php, json, twitter

The following PHP code used to work then this morning suddenly the following call

```
$get_tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" . $twitter_user_id . "&count=" . $tweets_to_display . "&include_rts=" . $include_rts . "&exclude_replies=" . $exclude_replies);
```

returns a $get_tweets with only one result even though I set count to 5 and I have many hundreds of tweets!
The only reason I see is that the previous tweet was 15 days ago however I want the latest 5 tweets not the latest 5 tweets in less than X days.

The library is the one available at https://github.com/andrewbiggart/latest-tweets-php-o-auth/ by the way.

**EDIT:**

```
$include_rts = false

$exclude_replies = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's correctly returning 5 tweets to me, however I noticed it returns only 1 from time to time but it must be a problem on Twitter side.

Probably from time to time they throttle the number of tweets independently of your request. You should in that case ignore updating the cache and use it instead of the returned single tweet.

Answer (score 2):

> Twitter user_timeline.json showing only latest tweet even though count
>   = 5

```
$get_tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" . $twitter_user_id . "&count=" . $tweets_to_display . "&include_rts=" . $include_rts . "&exclude_replies=" . $exclude_replies);
```

It's not a problem with `Twitter` side. Yes, `Twitter` will return the tweets how much you specified in `count` & if you didn't specified, it will return 15 tweets.

*So, Why `Twitter` returned only one tweet?*

It's because you used some additional parameters along with your request like

1. `include_rts` and
2. `exclude_replies`

which returns only few tweets.

Since you didn't provided about whether you enabled `retweets` and `excluded_replies` or not, i couldn't clearly point out you where you made the mistake.

But, most likely you're getting few tweets because of omitting Retweets or Replies or Both.

Comment: Both include_rts and exclude_replies were set to false, changing them had no result. Nevertheless I can't see how changing their values influences the output of count (I even put count=100 still got 1 tweet!).

Comment: I'm using the Twitter API from long ago. I hadn't faced the situation like you. May be you're doing wrong. Don't put too much value in count that results to no result since it takes too much time and your max execution time was few sec in default setting.